# simple navigation from 2nd activity to 3rd activity in android without passing any values

Tags: android

From first activity to second activity navigation is working but second activity to third activity navigation is not working in android can any1 please help me.

This is my MainActivity.java

---

```
package com.exampl.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void activity2(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.exampl.test.MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

This is my MainActivity2.java

```js
package com.exampl.test;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
      getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   }
   public void activity3(View view){
       Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.exampl.test.MainActivity3.class);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
       
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
    
         super.onBackPressed();
   }
    
}
```

This is my MainActivity3.java

```js
package com.exampl.test;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity3 extends Activity {

   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity3);
      getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   }
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
    
         super.onBackPressed();
   }
    
}
```

This is my appmanifest file

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exampl.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
         android:name="com.exampl.test.MainActivity2"
         android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2"
         android:parentActivityName="com.exampl.test.MainActivity" >
      </activity>
      <activity
         android:name="com.exampl.test.MainActivity3"
         android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity3"
         android:parentActivityName="com.exampl.test.MainActivity2" >
      </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please help me wt to modify in above coding
Thanks in advance

Comment: when is the activity3() method called?

Comment: When exactly should it be started? I also can't see when it should start the second activity.

Comment: public void activity3(View view){
       Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.exampl.test.MainActivity3.class);
       startActivity(intent);

Comment: this code is in second activity

Comment: if i click a button it should call another activity

Comment: from first activity to second activity it navigated

Comment: @SanjayKumar Have you defined an onClickListener for the button press. At the moment all we can see is a function that starts an intent but there is nothing calling that function.

Comment: Thanku @ boardy it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try This!

MainActivity

```
package com.example.acct;

import com.example.acct.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity2();
            }
        });
    }

    public void activity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.acct.MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

MainActivity2

```
 package com.example.acct;

import com.example.acct.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity3();
            }
        });
    }

    public void activity3() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.acct.MainActivity3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

MainActivity3

```
  package com.example.acct;

import com.example.acct.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity3 extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity3();
            }
        });
    }

    public void activity3() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.acct.MainActivity3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.acct"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.acct.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity2"
         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
      </activity>
      <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity3"
         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity2" >
      </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```